# ¿Porque el modal de bootstrap no funciona al momento de confirmar en blade de Laravel?

Tags: bootstrap-4, modal, laravel-blade, laravel-7, laravelcollective

estoy intentando eliminar un registro de una tabla con el modal de Bootstrap usando Laravel pero me encontre con el siguiente error que les muestro a continuación

[image: Código fuente HTML]

Cómo se puede observar, el modal si aparece y recupera los datos de la fila pero al momento de confirmar para que lo elimine, no realiza ninguna acción. Entre tanto que estaba fijandome, mire que en el Inspector esta lo siguiente
`<form action="http:127.0.0.1:8000/medicos/6" method="POST"></form>` La verdad no tengo idea porque esta maquetando así el HTML, ya revisé que todas las etiquetas esten con su apertura y cierre.

Este es el código donde obtengo la lista de médicos

[image: index.blade.php]

Aquí esta el código del modal usando Laravel Collective

[image: modal.blade.php]

Aquí el código del método destroy

[image: MedicoController]

Comment: El código que muestras está bien. Habría que ver en la ruta como lo seteaste. Me muestras el form y la ruta?

Comment: En la ruta tengo `Route::resource('medicos','MedicoController)`. en el modal esta el formulario, sólo que utilicé LaravelCollective pero viene a ser cómo:  

`<form action="{{  route('medicos.destroy',$medic->id) }}", method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>`

Comment: Si pones la ruta del destroy con un id existente en la url te elimina correctamente? yo verificaría que la ruta funcione. Si ahí está todo bien. Probaría de cambiar la ruta resource a get. Si nada de esto tiene efecto alguno apuntaría a ver que sucede en el html en la consola y el javascript. Fíjate de hacer estas pruebas y me vas avisando a ver que sucede.

Comment: De eliminarlo por la ruta, lo elimina correctamente, ya cambie la ruta de resource a get y sigue maquetando el html de la misma manera pero solo es esa parte, ya que use el modal en otra página y funciona correctamente. Por lo que no me quedó más opción de usar javascript usando xhr

Comment: Por lo tanto tenés un problema con el javascript en esa pagina. Bueno me alegro si resolviste el inconveniente. Saludos